# Gridview check all rows before update

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that has a sqldatasource. My Data should be like this:

[image: Desired]

But on any row, when I click EDIT button, and then "Update" button, I want to check that its previous row "Ending_Price" must be less than this row's Start_Price. Also This row's End_Price must be less than next Row's Start Price.

If this doesn' happen, then user must be notified as This range must be in order.

Here is my code:

```
        protected void UpdateRecord(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {


        if (e.RowIndex == 0 && GridView1.Rows.Count != 1)
        {
            // Next Row Starting Value
            TextBox txtNextStartingPoint = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex + 1].FindControl("txtStartingRange") as TextBox;

            // This row ending value
            TextBox txtThisEndingRange = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEndingRange") as TextBox;

            if (Convert.ToDecimal(txtThisEndingRange.Text) >= Convert.ToDecimal(txtNextStartingPoint))
            {
                NotificationHelper.ShowError(this, "Invalid Ending Value");
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }

        }

        TextBox txtStartingPoint = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtStartingRange") as TextBox;
        TextBox txtEndingRange = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEndingRange") as TextBox;
        TextBox txtDiscount_Percentage = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtDiscount_Percentage") as TextBox;
        Label txtDiscount_ID = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblId") as Label;


        SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["sr"].DefaultValue = txtStartingPoint.Text;
        SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["re"].DefaultValue = txtEndingRange.Text;
        SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["perc"].DefaultValue = txtDiscount_Percentage.Text;
        SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["discount_ID"].DefaultValue = txtDiscount_ID.Text;


        SqlDataSource1.Update();
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Edit record
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected void editRecord(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the current row index for edit record
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

    }


    protected void cancelRecord(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    }
```

This returns a null value:

```
  TextBox txtNextStartingPoint = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex + 1].FindControl("txtStartingRange") as TextBox;
```

Here is my gridview Markup

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                OnRowCancelingEdit="cancelRecord" OnRowEditing="editRecord" OnRowUpdating="UpdateRecord"
                CellPadding="4" GridLines="None" Width="673px" ForeColor="#333333" 
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound"
                >
                <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            Id</HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("discount_id")%>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            Starting Point</HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblStartingRange" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("starting_range") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartingRange" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("starting_range") %>'
                                MaxLength="50"></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewStartingRange" runat="server" MaxLength="50"></asp:TextBox>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            Ending Range</HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblEndingRange" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("ending_range") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndingRange" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("ending_range") %>'
                                MaxLength="2"></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndingRange" runat="server" MaxLength="2"></asp:TextBox>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            Discount Percentage</HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lbldiscount_percentage" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("discount_percentage") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDiscount_Percentage" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("discount_percentage") %>'
                                MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewDiscount_Percentage" runat="server" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            Operation</HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                            <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" CausesValidation="true"
                                OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                            <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="false" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    No record available
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
            </asp:GridView>
```

What should I do about it? Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

the others queries Return a value like this?

```
// This row ending value
TextBox txtThisEndingRange = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEndingRange") as TextBox;
```

or are they also null ?

you can try not to cast the Value try this.

```
var txtNextStartingPoint = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex + 1].FindControl("txtStartingRange")
```

perhaps its not a textbox what you get back.

Comment: txtThisEndingRange  is returning the correct value of the current row that is being editted... however txtNextStartingPoint  is null

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 points to be taken care of:

1.) Getting values of Current Row ( Row which is being edited )
**In this case, the values are inside `TextBox` control, since row is in Edit mode by now.**

```
// This row ending value
TextBox txtThisEndingRange = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEndingRange") as TextBox;
```

2.) Getting values from next row ( row next to the current row being edited )
**In this case, the row values are inside `Label` control, since row is not in `Edit` mode but is in `Normal` mode.**

This means that `<ItemTemplate>` controls are currently rendered by GridView and NOT the `<EditItemTemplate>` controls.

So now you can guess that you dont need to find `TextBox: txtStartingRange`, but you have to get the `Label: lblStartingRange`

```
// Next Row starting Value
Label lblNextStartRange= GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex + 1].FindControl("lblStartingRange") as Label;
```

and now do your normal checking/comparison of values as:

```
if (Convert.ToDecimal(txtThisEndingRange.Text) >= Convert.ToDecimal(lblNextStartRange.Text))
{
..
..
}
```